# What can I do as a co-signer?

Tags: auto-loan, co-sign

As a co-signer on an auto loan, how can I go about obtaining the vehicle if the other person defaults?

Both of our names are on the title as well.

Comment: What country and state?

Comment: Are you currently on the title, or does the title entirely belong to the other person?

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton i am on the title

Comment: @Rocky South Carolina, United States

Answer (score 12):

Unfortunately, co-signing the loan does not give you anything like the right to foreclose if the other person stops paying. To do that you would need a separate contract with the car's other owner, which I am presuming you don't have. Without paperwork, these are separate issues.

You need a lawyer. More accurately, you needed a lawyer before you co-signed the loan; there may not be much you can do now.